# Is there a way to count the number of matches in Vim using :g?

Tags: vim

I know this works:

```
:%s/<string>//gn
```

But it seems a bit strange to use the substitution command to count, rather than global..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've previously used a plugin for this. [vim-indexed-search](https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search) gives you a message in the command line such as:

```
2 of 32 matches
```

For searches using `/`

Answer (score 7):

It seems there's no other way. Indeed, this is the official way described in the Vim documentation.

See this SO question titled: [Counting occurrences in Vim without marking the buffer changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529/counting-occurrences-in-vim-without-marking-the-buffer-changed) and by extension [this paragraph from the Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items).

Alternatively there's this SO question too, titled: [Search for string and get count in vi editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715643/search-for-string-and-get-count-in-vi-editor), but note that this method will only count lines not actual matches, so if you have multiple matches per line, you'll not get a correct count.